# How can I make <div> elements responsive inside <nav> element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

so I was making a dashboard page for this bot and the page looks good on desktop , but isn't responsive on mobile devices.

**THE PAGE ON DESKTOP**

[image: desktop preview]

**THE PAGE ON MOBILE DEVICES**

[image: Mobile Preview]

**THE CODE FOR PAGE**

**HTML**

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link id="theme" href="/static/css/light.css" aria-labelledby="dark" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Steve.</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg text-div">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <a href="/"><img id="navbar_dicord_brand" src="/static/images/discord_logo_black.svg" width="120" height="60"></a>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <li>
                        <a class="spacing" style="padding-right:.5em" href="#"></span><strong>Commands</strong></a>
                        <span id="number_badge" class="top-0 start-100 translate-middle badge rounded-pill" style="background-color: crimson;">16<span class="visually-hidden">unread messages</span>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="spacing" href="https://top.gg/bot/834409783502438480/invite/"><strong>Invite</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a class="spacing" href="https://discord.gg/JEDu42vVBX"><strong>Support Server</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a class="spacing" href="https://www.patreon.com/ks47"><strong>Patreon</strong></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <a class="navbar-brand a_text" href="https://top.gg/bot/834409783502438480">
                        <img src="/static/images/avtar.webp" width="45" height="45">
                        <strong>Steve.</strong>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="body_container">
            <div>
                <center>
                    <div class="container text-div" style="width: fit-content;" >
                        <h1 class="display1 text_font">Anime and Manga in your Discord Server.</h1>
                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="container text-div" style="margin-top:3%">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col" style="text-align: left;">
                            <h1 class="display1"><img id="clyde_icon" src="/static/images/icon_clyde_black_RGB.svg" width="45px" height="45px"> {{count}} Guilds</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" style="text-align: center;">
                            <h1 class="display1"><img id="hash_icon" src="/static/images/hashtag.svg" width="45px" height="30px">{{channels}} Channels</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" style="text-align: right;">
                            <h1 class="display1"><img id="user_icon" src="/static/images/user_svg.svg"> {{users}} Users</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
                        <h5 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Footer text 1</h5>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita sapiente sint, nulla, nihil
                                repudiandae commodi voluptatibus corrupti animi sequi aliquid magnam debitis, maxime quam recusandae
                                harum esse fugiat. Itaque, culpa?
                            </p>
                    </div>
                    <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-3">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mb-md-0 mb-3">
                        <h5 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Footer text 2</h5>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio deserunt fuga perferendis modi earum
                            commodi aperiam temporibus quod nulla nesciunt aliquid debitis ullam omnis quos ipsam, aspernatur id
                            excepturi hic.
                        </p>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

**CSS 1**

```css
.spacing{
        font-family: 'Whitney','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
}
a.spacing{
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        padding-right: 1.5em;
}
a.spacing:hover{
        color: crimson;
}
.text_font{
        font-family: 'Whitney','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,'Lucida Grande','sans-serif';
}
.body_container{
        margin-top: 10%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        font-family: 'Whitney','Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,'Lucida Grande','sans-serif';
        font-size: 2vw;
        
}
```

**CSS 2**

```css
body{
        background-color: white;
        background-image:url(/static/images/background1.jpg);
        background-size: cover;    
        color: black;
}    
.a_text{
        color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-family: Whitney,'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,'Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
}
a.a_text:hover{
        color: crimson;
        text-decoration: none;
}
.footer{
        background-color:rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.884);
        color: black;
        margin-top: 10%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
}
.text-div{
        background-color: rgba(247, 247, 247, 0.882);
        color: black;
}
.spacing{
        color: black;
}
```

So I need to make sure that the divs in nav bar are responsive I **TRIED** Some `@media` queries but didn't got the desired results so is there a way that the navbar can be responsive and the center div objects would appear like a list

something like the image below

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example... But before...

- Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to the `head` section in your code -> [Viewport Meta Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).
- **Don't** use `<center>` element to center content:

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

sourse: [MDN - Center Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)

Use `flexbox`, `grid` or `positioning` property -> [Center Anything is CSS](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-center-anything-with-css-align-a-div-text-and-more/).

- Some `elements` in **your** code (in `navbar`) doesn't have a `closing tag`.

#### The Code:

Open code in full screen and resize the window.

```js
var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var list_container = document.querySelector('.list-container');

burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    list_container.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {list-style-type: none;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

.navbar-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {.navbar-container {max-width: 100%;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) {.navbar-container {max-width: 760px;}}
@media (min-width: 992px) {.navbar-container {max-width: 960px;}}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {.navbar-container {max-width: 1180px;}}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo-container a:link, 
.logo-container a:visited {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #151515;
}

.logo-container ion-icon {
    color: #151515;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.logo-container span {
    font-size: 30px;
}

.list-container {
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.list-container.active {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.list-container ul {
    display: flex;
}

.list-container ul li {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.list-container ul li a:link,
.list-container ul li a:visited,
.brand-container a:link,
.brand-container a:visited {
    color: #151515;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.burger {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.burger span {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #121212;
}

.burger span:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:992px){
    .list-container ul li a:link,
    .list-container ul li a:visited {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
    }
    .brand-container {
        display: none;
    }
    .list-container {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        top: 80px;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .list-container ul {
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    .list-container ul li {
        margin: unset;
    }
    .list-container ul li {
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.4.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>


<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-container">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <a href="#">
                <ion-icon name="logo-discord"></ion-icon>
                <span>Discord</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="list-container">
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support Server</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Patreon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="brand-container">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="..." alt="...">
                <span>Steve</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="burger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox with @media queries, it will help you. Change the flex-direction from raw  to column on mobile device width.  :)